# Sub-hamiltionian graph example

Tags: graph-theory

A sub-Hamiltonian graph is a graph G which is **not** Hamiltonian and also for every vertex $ u $ where $ u\in V(G) $ the graph $ G-{u}$ is a Hamiltonian graph.

Now can somebody tell me if it is possible to create a sub-Hamiltonian graph with $V(G)\le 16 $ and at least 1 vertex must have degree at least 8?($ \exists u\in V(G),deg(u)\ge8) $

If such graph does not exist, can somebody tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a$ be a vertex with degree at least $8$.  The remaining vertices form a cycle of length at most $15$, so some two adjacent vertices in this cycle must be neighbours of $a$.  But then you get a Hamiltonian cycle by inserting $a$ between these two.

Comment: ok got it!! thanks for the help!!

Comment: Suppose not.  Going around the cycle, you have at least $8$ that are neighbours of $a$, and another $8$ that follow a neighbour of $a$, but that makes $16$ which is too many.

Comment: yes i figured it out. but thanks for the help anyway!